# what is the difference between MQ and MQTT?

Tags: message-queue, mqtt, mq

I am beginner to MQTT , but what is confusing me is it's basic definition

> MQTT is a publish-subscribe based "light weight" messaging protocol'.

Based on my previous understanding on MQ (Message Queue), both MQ and MQTT sounds very same to me. Can any one elaborate what the real difference between MQ and MQTT is and their use case? Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MQTT is a protocol, it is open source.  A lot of vendors are using this protocol for messaging.

MQ is an over-arching team that just means messaging.  There are lot of different protocols, AMQP is one of them as well.

Additionally, IBM had a product called MQ.

Comment: There is also a distinct difference between pub/sub and message queuing. pub/sub is 1 to many where as message queuing tends to be more 1 to 1 (single consumer)

Comment: @Jeff, thanks for your answer. From your answers perspective can we say MQTT is an MQ protocol?

Comment: @student yeah, MQTT is an MQ protocol.

Answer (score 6):

MQTT was initially called "Message Queue Telemetry Transport". You can find an in-depth explanation how it evolved here: http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-essentials-part-1-introducing-mqtt/

Comment: In the second post, it says for a message queue broker:  A message queue stores message until they are consumed; A message is only consumed by one client; Queues are named and must be created explicitly. https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part2-publish-subscribe

Answer (score 1):

MQTT is an [OASIS](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=mqtt) standard protocol that is not only used for MQ messaging but it can also be used for the Internet of Things IOT and M2M (machine to machine) communication.

Here is a [slide presentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024986&aid=1) that you may find useful.